# declaring nested generic in java

Tags: java, generics, nested-generics

I have an `ApiResponse` generic class with type parameter `T` like this

```
public class ApiResponse<T extends Parcelable> {

    ...
    @SerializedName("result")
    private T result;
    ...

}
```

and I have another class ApiCallback like this

```
public abstract class ApiCallback<T>  {
     private T result; // in the example is refered to ApiResponse<UserMessage> but i want to access UserMessage
}
```

and this is the code im calling the classes

```
new ApiCallback<ApiResponse<UserMessage>>() {
                    @Override
                    protected void onSuccess(Call<ApiResponse<UserMessage>> call, Response<ApiResponse<UserMessage>> response) {
                        UserMessage result = response.body().getResult();

                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onError(Call<ApiResponse<UserMessage>> call, Response<ApiResponse<UserMessage>> response) {

                    }
                }
```

### question

the T parameter in the `ApiCallback` is refered to the `ApiResponse<UserMessage>` how can i access the inner type parameter the `UserMessage` ?

thanks in advance

Comment: If you're asking about getting access to a `UserMessage` instance outside of your listener/APICallback, that somewhat defeats the point of non blocking io done like this (you'd need to block the current thread to retrieve it). Typically new events/tasks are fired off from something like that